# Arcgis missing method option for "Near" tool

Tags: arcgis

I'm using arcgis to find the nearest distance from my lat/lon points to coastline. I use the near tool in arcgis. however, i realize that the "Geodesic option" is missing from the arcgis i'm using. i suspect this is a version problem, does anyone know?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `Method` parameter (allowing you to choose between `PLANAR` and `GEODESIC`) was added in ArcGIS 10.2.1, so you're probably using an older version indeed.

See [What's new in ArcGIS 10.2.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_s_new_in_ArcGIS_10_2_1/016w0000005v000000/) for reference.